# Hello World in Ember.js: what's wrong here?

Tags: ember.js

I've prepared a Fiddle to better expose the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xbxwr/

Code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({ templateName: "MyView" });

App.myCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.create({
    itemViewClass: App.MyView,
    content: [
        Ember.Object.create({ name: "World" }),
        Ember.Object.create({ name: "Foo" }),
        Ember.Object.create({ name: "Bar" })
    ]
});

$(function() { App.initialize(); });
```

View :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
   {{collection App.myCollectionView}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="MyView">
  <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
</script>​
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `{{collection}}` helper needs a `Ember.View` class instead of an `Ember.View` instance. You have to replace `Ember.CollectionView.create()` with `Ember.CollectionView.extend`.

Next, in your template, you have to replace `{{name}}` with `{{view.content.name}}`, according to [View context changes](https://gist.github.com/2494968).

Here is your updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AzV4f/

**EDIT**

Writing `{{name}}` means `context.name`, where context is usually the controller ([see source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L618)). And as `Ember.ObjectController`, `Ember.ArrayController` are just proxy, these property are delegated to their content([see ObjectProxy source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/object_proxy.js#L104)).

So you have to write `{{view.content.name}}`, because you want the `name` property of the `view.content`.

As @tomdale said [in this gist comment](https://gist.github.com/2494968#gistcomment-345434):

> Inside your item view's template, `view` should reference the item view,
>   and `view.content` should reference the item in your content array.

And you can see the JSFiddle with a controller, without specifying `view`: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xp2ss/)

Comment: Thanks @lousicoquio, I read [the view context changes](https://gist.github.com/2494968) gist during my researches, but my understanding was that on new versions of Ember, `{{name}}` would refer to a property in the `content`, instead of the view. So why do I need to explicitly use `{{view.content.XXX}}`?